# Cannot block traffic to specific address

Tags: linux, ufw

By using iftop on Ubuntu 16.04 I found there's a constant connection to `108.61.10.10.choopa.net`.

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:47912           => 108.61.10.10.choopa.net                  0b      0b      0b
                                 <=                                          0b      0b      0b
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:54461           => 108.61.10.10.choopa.net                  0b      0b      0b
                                 <=                                          0b      0b      0b
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:38456           => 108.61.10.10.choopa.net                  0b      0b      0b
                                 <=                                          0b      0b      0b
```

> Note: I replaced my host ip with XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

As I cannot find which process is connecting to it I would like to block all network traffic to that ip.

To do that I added this rule to my ufw:

```
sudo ufw deny from 108.61.10.10
sudo ufw deny to 108.61.10.10
```

But those didn't blocked the proccess.

Any hint?.

Edit: here's the relevant part of `ufw status`:

```
108.61.10.10               DENY        Anywhere
Anywhere                   DENY        108.61.10.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you perhaps provide the output of `sudo ufw status`?
Perhaps too obvious but is the ufw service enabled?

Alternatively you could try running `ss -tp` to find the pid('s) corresponding to the 108.61.10.10 connections.

Edited:
Note that 108.61.10.10.choopa.net is a dns name and not an ip address, hence blocking the ip address 108.61.10.10 might be working as expected but the actual source address is a different one which in this case isn't being blocked causing the connection to remain active.

As far as I can tell the actual ip addresses for this domain name are:
ns1.choopadns.com internet address = 68.232.191.191
ns2.choopadns.com internet address = 68.232.191.232

Comment: I've added the output of ufw status. Also `ss -tp` does not show those processes.

Comment: I've edited my previous post, you will have to change the configured ip adress

Comment: Thanks, I added them to the deny rules, but it isn't blocked.

Comment: Can you try to lookup this hostname on the server you want to block the connection from? The address I've given you are pointing at dns servers in this choopa domain. When I do a nslookup on the choopa.net itself I get a different ip adres:

`(;; ANSWER SECTION:
choopa.net.             44      IN      A       64.237.47.23`

Can you identify the connection using `netstat lntuwp`? Not sure which command you've used to monitor the connection but it seems to me like its resolving the ip addresses.

Comment: This is really weird, I did a `watch netstat --inet lntuwpb` for about 2 minutes and I can only see allowed connections.

Comment: And is the command you've used before to monitor the same connection still showing the same output?

Comment: Yes, it's still there...

Comment: Can you tell me how you check this? Is it through a command or application? Which? Is restarting the network interface an option(would logically break the opened connections) ?